# nodejs getting top 10 apps' cpu usages

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the top 5 or 10 apps from the server by their CPU usages with NodeJS. I can get all memory, disk properties by ('os') lib but is there a way to get memory, CPU usages for a specific app. Not for all system's.

Regards

Comment: For all systems or specific one?

Comment: For windows servers applications. I want to see the top 5 applications from the task manager with their cpu, ram usages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that information in several ways, here one using the *[current-processes](https://github.com/branneman/current-processes)* package (in fact, this is the usage example of that library):

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const ps = require('current-processes');

ps.get((err, processes) => {
  if (err) throw err
  let sorted = _.sortBy(processes, 'cpu');
  let top5 = sorted.reverse().splice(0, 5);
  console.log(top5);
});
```

This will output the top 5 processes ordered by cpu usage.
In fact, the library get all the processes and we just filter the result to get the information we need.

The same way we can filter only one process if we need to. By example, if we want to find the cpu usage of *Firefox* process:

```
const ps = require('current-processes');

ps.get((err, processes) => {
  if (err) throw err
  processes.map(process => {
    if (process.name == 'firefox')
      console.log(process)
  });
});
```

Or, if you do not want any dependencies, you can do it directly with for exemple ths `ps` command (on Linux). This is anyway how the *current-processes* library do it internally:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('ps -C firefox -o %cpu,%mem', (err, stdout) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(stdout)
})
```

Comment: This is totally what I was looking for. Thank you